# Handling an Integrity constraint violation with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, relational-database

I know there are similar questions on SO, but I didn't find an answer to this one.

When I try to delete an entity of class `EntityA` that has a oneToMany association to another class `EntityB` and there is an `EntityB` associated with `EntityA` I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`example_table`.`entity_b`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAC822D9B8F92CD8` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_a_id`) REFERENCES `entity_a` (`id`))
```

(I changed the real entity names to `EntityA` and `EntityB`)

I tried to configure Doctrine to set the foreignkey on the owning side of that relation to `NULL` via the `cascade` setting. But I think, because I use it on the *not-owning-side* it does not work. But I am not sure if that is the case.

**EDIT**: in fact I am really unsure what the cascade:detach option should else do if it is set on the owning side. Perhaps I am missing some understanding of doctrine essentials ...

I know there are SQL-triggers (that can do operations on delete events etc.) and also a way to configure doctrine to configure them, but I would like to keep that logic inside my application code.

I also would like to avoid iterating over collections, checking if relations are set and then setting them to `NULL` because of performance reasons.

What am I doing wrong? How can the error thrown be avoided?

Here are the two relevant mapping definitions in the entity classes:

EntityA

```
class EntityA {
    /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"detach"})
     */
    private $entityBs;
}
```

EntityB

```
class EntityB {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entityB")
   */
  private $entityA;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $entityBs;
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entityB")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entityA_id", referencedColumnName="entityB_id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $entityA;
```

Comment: OK, seems like `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"remove"})` is not necessary. But the `onDelete="SET NULL"` option does the trick. How does it work internally? I thought it sets a trigger inside the MySQL table. But I cannot see any triggers, if I inspect that table via mysql cli. Thanks anyway.